# Модальное/диалоговое окно всплывающее из кнопки/элемента

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Есть задача, где необходимо показать модальное окно, будто всплывающее из кнопки (в конечном результате отображается, по центру экрана), есть ли какие-то готовые реализации данного функционала в MUI или сторонние решение и если нет, то как подобное можно реализовать?

Подойдет анимация появления/закрытия как в MacOS:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/

Comment: Там нет того, что я ищу.

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-modal/ вот тут посмотри

Comment: или вот всплывающее окно по нажатию кнопки https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/

Comment: Вы наверное неправильно поняли вопрос. Я знаю о модалках, вопрос был в том, чтобы она показалась с анимацией, будто вылезла из кнопки.

Comment: Таких библиотек не знаю, но думаю такого эффекта можно добиться с помощью CSS-анимаций и [transform: scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)